# Phase of FMCW linear chirp

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency, phase, radar

I'm doing a project involving FMCW linear chirp signals.

Given the phase

$\phi = 2\pi\frac{k}{2}t^{2} + 2\pi f_{c} t + \theta$

where $k$ is the frequency increase rate.

When transmitting frequency modulated pulses continiously will the phase increase in this manner?

[image]

Or simply repeat in this manner?

[image]

What is the advantages and disadvantages of either one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that phase is usually only defined on the $[0;2\pi[$ interval (or on $[-\pi;+\pi[$). When you do that $\mod 2\pi$ operation on your graphs, you'll notice that there's no significant difference between your two plots.